# Content Assist (class proposals) for Linked CSS in HTML, in Eclipse

Tags: html, css, eclipse

**When linking to a CSS file in HTML, I am not getting any proposals from Eclipse neon on classes in the linked CSS.**

I have tried the below with both "Eclipse for PHP" and "Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Development".

To replicate the issue:

1) Open Eclipse neon, and create a new Static Web Project

2) Create a new html and css file

3) In the HTML, link to the CSS file like you otherwise would:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type=" text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

4) In the CSS file, add any class definition:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.testClass {
    broder: 1px solid red;
}
```

5) When writing the div element in the html: "class=..." is not bringing up any suggestions from the linked css, which is in the same folder as the html. ctrl+space is giving 0 suggestions as well, it just cycles through HTML Proposals etc, which are blank.

I have double-checked the settings under 'Window --> Preferences --> Web --> CSS/HTML Files --> Editor --> Content Assist'

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?